# how to earn a transaction fee for transactions originating from my client

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, address, transaction-fees

I am working on an online litecoin wallet system. For every transaction originated from our site, we need to charge say x% of the amount as fees and it'll be sent to Admin's address ? How can I do that ?

I guess `paytxfee` is what we are willing to pay others for a particular transaction, right ?

I didn't found any parameter to set the address to which the transaction fees should go ?

Looking for some help...

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly.  You want to charge a fee, such as LTC .005 for a transaction that you originate, and then also (or in addition) collect the standard Litecoin transaction fee to pass along to the network?

Comment: how is the standard litecoin transaction fee collected and which address does it go to ?

Comment: It goes to the miner who incorporates that transaction into a block. This is not the sort of fee mechanism you're looking for. Just charge a bit extra.

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks, please put it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, "transaction fee" is the difference between sum of inputs and sum of outputs. It always goes to the miner.

What you need is to add an output payable to your account.

Comment: You mean to say make another transaction in the back-end for the fees from user-address to admin-address ?